# Are there any useful naming conventions for *your* constant/static variable in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, coding-style

I know that constants start with the `k` prefix, but does anyone have their own constant prefix, so they can easily get completion on their constants, instead of Apple's?

I use a three letter prefix for my classes because of my company name, let's pretend it's `OMG`. I tried prefixing my constants with `omgkConstantName` but that isn't very satisfying. I was also toying with either `kk` or `ok` (the *o* is from the OMG.) Or maybe I should do kOMGConstantName, that seems more Cocoa-ish?

It seems really useful to quickly get to your own constants, the same way you might want to get to your own classes. Does anyone do this? Is it terrible Cocoa style?

Also, is there a good naming convention for static variables you would only use in one class, like keys for a JSON dictionary? Should they have the `k`? Should they start uppercase, or do they follow normal case conventions?

```
// Static Variables
static NSString *searchTextKey = @"searchText";
static NSString *searchResultsKey = @"searchResults";
(more)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try to consistently use `kJAFoo` (or `kXXFoo` where XX is a project prefix) for my public constants – especially actual `const`s which are exported symbols – but generally use `kFoo` for enums or `static const`s inside an implementation file. Similarly, I use `sFoo` for static variables and `gJAFoo` in the rare cases where I use exported globals.

None of these cases are as important as namespacing classes (and methods in categories on imported classes), though, since most types of conflicts will emerge at compile or link time rather than runtime.

Comment: This is more or less how I do it. It's subjective though.

Comment: Oh thats sounds very clear and logic. **k** for `const`, **g** for `extern` and **s** for `static`. *External linkage* with the 2 or 3 letter code. Apple even says that you should use the *whole class name* in external linked variables (*g* and *k*) instead of only the letter code.

Comment: What to do with **static const**? Only add **k* and then *Pascal Case*... `kPoints`

Comment: @Godric, Where is `k` found in `const` or `g` in `extern`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei k and g as prefixes are used in many frameworks (g in almost only old ones), Apple did use k as prefix themself (some apis did have them, but I think new ones won't get them). Googles guidelines did encourage you to use prefixes. But I think coding guidelines shifted away from prefixes. Third party frameworks on GitHub uses them here and there. Global variables are dangerous, many say you should not use them at all, so you won't really see the g prefix because there aren't any. Extern const are prefixed just with k almost all of the time.

Comment: @Godric, I know, but I didn't understand how did you find `very clear and logic` that `k` is for `const`. Why not `c` for `const` like `s` is for `static`.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei "g" because I and everyone around me use the naming "global" instead of "extern variable", global is more universal for programming than extern. So using the extern as a keyword in C/Objective-C, but saying global to it. "k" because I speak german ;-), "Konstante" means "constant" in german.

Answer (score 6):

Apple's [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) recommends to use the same naming conventions for enumerations as for functions. Following this advice, *OMGConstantName* would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I normally make constants Pascal case.

If you choose to follow the 'namespacing convention' of putting a prefix on everything then you'd use that as well.

So I'd normally do

```
static NSString *SearchTextKey = @"searchText";
```

you may choose to namespace it though which would have it be (assuming your prefix is ZK)

```
static NSString *ZKSearchTextKey = @"searchText";
```

In general I only namespace things that are used in multiple projects, following the google recommendation (or at least it was when I was settling upon my naming convention).

The most important thing though is that whatever convention you settle on.  Stick to it and be consistent (at least within a given project).  At a certain point second guessing yourself is just going to waste time.

Comment: Definitely agree about consistency. I'm just starting a new multi-Xcode-project project and have the opportunity to set the style convention. I think I'm leaning towards `kOMG` as the prefix. I like being able to tell between constants and classes.

Answer (score 1):

I usually follow the same prefix/capitalisation convention as classes, so where Cocoa has `NSTouchPhaseBegan` I might have `GLTuneNameKey`.